# Android: android:textOn and android:textOff on Switch not working

Tags: android

Changing the `android:textOn` and `android:textOff` attributes of `Switch` does not work on my S3. The label on my switch always shows *"ON"* and *"OFF"*.

[`Switch` Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#attr_android%3atextOff)

```
<Switch
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textOn="@string/on"
                        android:textOff="@string/off"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"/>
```

Comment: Does it work in an equivalent emulator? If yes, then Samsung perhaps messed with the implementation of `ToggleButton`.

Comment: Is there any stable backport of the Switch widget?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S3, and it works just fine.

Here's my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:textOn="CHANGEMEON"
        android:textOff="CHANGEMOFF"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is using a ToggleButton instead of a Switch, although the text labels are correct it's a different UI element / not ideal if you need a Switch.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code :

```
      toggle=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglbtn);
      toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(toggle.isChecked())
      {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The state is changed to on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
        else
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The state is changed to off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         }
         });
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to the question.

Comment: I am testing my application on various models and I have realized that the toggle button ON and OFF event is not working. This is the list of devices:

Samsung YS5360 Samsung Galaxy Note Samsung S Plus HTC Sensation XE HTC Wildfire S Motorola RAZR
LG Optimus Black Sony Ericsson Xperia neo V   but i have implemented the above code it is working check once.......